# How to make a startup script handle brute-force shutdown?

Tags: debian, scripting

I'm using Termux on Android, but the question applies here. How can I make a script run at startup and handle emergency shutdown? I'm looking for a script to run a vncserver and and stop it during shutdown/exit.

Comment: On debian you want to have vncserver automatically started at boot?

Comment: Pretty much. But I also want it to handle hard poweroff. It's possible, right?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-debian-10